# How to log sql in grails 1.3.7

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I try to configure logs for sql in grails with logSql=true in datasource (test env) but nothing is displayed in test output.

I read this post but It's not working.

[How to log SQL statements in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568507/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-grails)

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We did it in Config.groovy,

```
log4j = {
// ... whatever

    debug    'org.hibernate.SQL',
             'org.hibernate.transaction' // optionally
}
```

[Log4j is configured differently since Grails 1.1.](http://www.grails.org/1.1+Release+Notes)