# GORM self referencing trees and performance

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm implementing a self-reference GORM object for a message board.  So far, pseudo GORM class:

```
class Article {
  String title
  Article parent
  static belongsTo = [parent: Article]
  static hasMany = [children: Article] 

  static constraints = {
    parent(nullable: true)
  }

  static transients = ['descendants', 'ancestors']

  def getDescendants() {
     return children ? children*.descendants.flatten() + children : []
  }

  def getAncestors() {
     return parent ? parent.ancestors.flatten() + this : []
  }
}
```

So, this works fine on my local box, but will it scale on site with thousands of daily uniques is my concern.

Ever since Burt Beckwith's presentation http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance and I'm inclined to not use hasMany / belongsTo.

It's going to be primarily read of the messages vs adding new.

I could cache the getDescendants and getAncestors calls.

I could add a new boolean called "hasChildren".  This field could be manipulated with override addToChildren and removeFromChildren methods.  The use of "hasChildren" could prevent things like

```
if (article.children.size() > 0) // show replies
```

instead:

```
if (article.hasChildren) // show replies
```

Thoughts?  Suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Todd

Answer (score 0):

I would just try it with [SQL logging on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193539/how-to-log-sql-in-grails-1-3-7/5193698#5193698). BTW why don't you use [mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html)?