# Grails - unsaved transient instance exception

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am trying to upgrade a Grails app from 1.0.3 to 1.3.7 and ran into the exception:

```
 object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
```

I am not doing any saves in the code that triggers. It is in the following code

```
public static Season getCurrentSeason() {
        String yearString = ConfigurationHolder.config.year
        assert yearString != null: "need to configure season"
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearString)

        Affiliation nfl = Affiliation.nfl;
        return Season.findBySeasonKeyAndLeague(year, nfl)
    }
```

The call to Affiliation.nfl is:

```
public static Affiliation getNfl() {
           if (cacheNFL == null) {
            String key = ConfigurationHolder.config.nfl
            cacheNFL = Affiliation.findByKey(key)
        }
        return cacheNFL;
    }
```

If I removed the cacheNFL and make it do a real fetch each time, the code works. My questions are:

- Why did this work before? It seems
  like making a fetch with a cached
  object that isn't part of the current
  Hibernate query (which I am, perhaps
  incorrectly, assuming is the problem)
  would never be supported.
- Is there
  anyway around this problem aside from
  making a fetch to the database?
- How
  can I tell if I am hitting the
  database or going to a Hibernate
  cache (I don't know much about
  Hibernate). Is there output that can
  show me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It's `findBy*` that triggers a `flush()` - every `Criteria` flushes any object that can be potentially returned by that `Criteria`.
   This is done in order to ensure that `Criteria` returns all the matching objects.
   Looks like this logic was introduced in 1.1.
2. Try fetching the object in `Affiliation.withNewSession{ }`. Or, better, fetch it before you begin your current transaction/in the beginning of transaction, before the `flush()`ed objects get dirty.
3. Enable Grails sql logging: [How to log sql in grails 1.3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193539/how-to-log-sql-in-grails-1-3-7/5193698#5193698)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't really know what you mean in your first and second points - I'm pretty new to this. So when I pass in my cached Affiliation object it flushes it, which calls a save essentially? Can you elaborate more on your points? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: 1. It's not a cached entity, but a cache ititialization (your `Affiliation.findByKey()`) that causes `flush()`. `flush()` is, yes, like a `save()`, writes the changes to database. Only that it is not committed - it will be rolled back automatically if you `discard()` it or don't actually `save()` anything. (I might be wrong about Hibernate internals here, but it's the idea)

Comment: 2. In order not to `flush()` your current Hibernate session (http://www.coderanch.com/t/218534/ORM/java/Difference-between-commit-flush-Hibernate), you can run a code in a different `Session` - it's what `.withNewSession{ }` does. Though, you won't be able to save/connect an object from a different session, until you `attach()` (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html) it to your current session.