# CreateCriteria with projections does not select all columns

Tags: grails, projection, createcriteria

My Question is exactly like 
[Grails Projections not returning all properties and not grouped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911615/grails-projections-not-returning-all-properties-and-not-grouped)

I have a following criteria

```
def sharedDocumentsInstanceList SharedDocuments.createCriteria().list(params){
   createAlias('receiver', 'r')
   createAlias('author', 'a')
   eq("r.id",session.uid)  
   projections{
      groupProperty("a.id")
      property("a.firstName","firstName")
      property("a.lastName","lastName")
      property("a.emailAddress","email")
   }
}
```

Where sharedDocuments is defined as follows

```
class SharedDocuments {
   Users author
   Users receiver
   Documents file
}
```

What I have seen is that sharedDocumentsInstanceList always has only the last property mentioned in the projection. I can use the same query in "withCriteria" but I seem to loose the groovy goodness of automatic pagination with it because withCriteria does not return paged pagedresultlist!

Comment: createAlias('receiver', 'r')
 createAlias('author', 'a') this stuff helps much !

Comment: I've opened a JIRA to this issue. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10589

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of those still having this issue; Remove the provided `params` object on the list method. So the criteria query above becomes:

```
def sharedDocumentsInstanceList = SharedDocuments.createCriteria().list {
    createAlias('receiver', 'r')
    createAlias('author', 'a')
    eq("r.id",session.uid)  
    projections {
        groupProperty("a.id")
        property("a.firstName","firstName")
        property("a.lastName","lastName")
        property("a.emailAddress","email")
    }
    maxResults(params.max)
    firstResult(params.offset)
    order(params.sort, params.order)
}
```

Comment: You can add `resultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)` if you prefer familiar grails-like query result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    projections{                
        author {
           groupProperty("id")
           property("firstName","firstName")
           property("lastName","lastName")
           property("emailAddress","email")
        }
    }
```

Would using the above approach yield different results?  Just a thought...

Comment: Nope, I got rid of the count and wrote the criteria as you suggested but it still only prints the emailAddress.