# Grails PostgreSQL and umlauts

Tags: java, grails, jpa, jdbc, encoding

My PostgreSQL query returns no results when a search string starts with an German umlaut like `Ö`. I am using `ilike` to get my results.

The problem is if only the first letter is an umlaut....
The PostgreSQL query alone works fine. There seems to be the problem with the combination of grails. Making further research I found out there is a problem with ilike when I change it to like it works fine.

```
def searchResult = Termin.createCriteria().listDistinct{

                    or  {                       
                          ilike('vorname', '%' + searchString.trim() + '%')
                          ilike('nachname', '%' + searchString.trim() + '%')
                    }

                    order('nachname', 'asc')
                    maxResults(27) 
                }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. [Check this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/2eb08/1)

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version? If it's 8.4 or older, upgrade, unicode pattern matching was improved greatly in newer versions. Otherwise, please show your locale and charset; see `\l+` in `psql`

Comment: I have a version 9.1. I am using grails as my framework maybe the problem is related to that.

Comment: Regular expressions in Postgres accept accentuated characters. So `field ~ '^Ö'` will work.

Comment: The condition content is from a search field so it is dynamically created...

Comment: Can you enable sql output to see what Hibernate is generating? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568507/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-grails

Comment: I've seen a number of cases in Python where the problem was due to character encoding issues in the Python rather than the underlying PostgreSQL database, although it's not a bad idea to make sure the underlying tables are in UTF-8 encoding (the default for some years now).