# Grails lower() in query not working

Tags: grails, lowercase

Let's say I have code like this:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    or {
        like("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
        like("holderFirstName", "Barney%")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

I want to use lower() function to transforming data to lower case

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    or {


        like("lower(holderFirstName)", "Fred%")
        like("lower(holderFirstName)", "Barney%")


    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

My code doesn't work. What is the correct syntax? I have a problem with umlauts so I don't want to use `ilike`

Comment: What's your problem with umlauts and ilike?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538466/grails-postegresql-and-umlauts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use database functions in a criteria you need to use `sqlRestriction()` that add's restrictions directly to the generated sql.

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
...
  sqlRestriction("lower(holder_first_name) like '%%'")
}
```

Note that with this you use your column name, and not attribute name.

Comment: This work fine and just how I wanted. But I have another problem if the first letter is an german umlaut no results are found although a record is the database

Answer (score 3):

Don't know which `lower` function you'd like to use but I guess you want to fetch data based on `holderFirstName` property ignoring the case.

Here you could use `ilike`, which is an case-insensitive `like`:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    between("balance", 500, 1000)
    eq("branch", "London")
    or {
        ilike("holderFirstName", "Fred%")
        ilike("holderFirstName", "Barney%")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("holderLastName", "desc")
}
```

By the way - you missed to call `list()` on your criteria ...

**Update**

You could try to add a `formula` to your domain class like this:

```
static mapping = {
   lowerFirstName formula: "lower(holder_first_name)"
```

}

and change the property in your criteria to `lowerFirstName`:

```
like("lowerFirstName", "fred%") // changed 'Fred%' to 'fred%'
```

Code is not tested but should work.

Comment: You should also need to add lowerFirstName in your entity class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to compare for case insensitivity, another option is to use ilike for that purpose. Ilike is similar to Like, but its case insensitive. [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

If you do not want to use ilike (as added to the question), I think you alternative approach is executeQuery and hql.

```
Account.executeQuery(" select * from Account where .... or (lower(holderFirstName) = 'Fred%' ...")
```

Comment: Can't I somehow make it work with the default criteria I have. I dont get it it just a function call and it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in createCriteria other than ilike, maybe others have a better solution.