# Hibernate criteria subquery referring to value from "root" query

Tags: hibernate, groovy, hibernate-criteria

I'm working in Grails & Groovy but this is a hibernate question.  Here's my Grails domain class:

```
public Card {
    // implicit Long id
    String name

    // ... and over a dozen other fields with various types.
}
```

I currently have this Hibernate query:

```
def name = "foo"

def result = session.createQuery("from Card as c where lower(c.name) like ? and c.id in (select max(c2.id) from Card as c2 where c.name = c2.name)")
        .setString(0, "%${name}%")
        .list()
```

This gets all Cards with names containing the substring "foo", skipping over any Cards with duplicate names except for the "newest" (I'm assuming that higher ID means 'newer').  **I must avoid returning Cards with duplicate names.**

In addition to filtering on the name and dodging the duplicate-names problem, I need to filter and/or sort on the other fields in Card.  I also need to paginate.  I wanted to use the Criteria API to do this, since the approach of generating SQL/HQL leads to maintainability nightmares.

I just can't understand how to do this kind of querying via Criteria API though.  There are the detached queries that can be used as a subquery via the Criteria API.  However these subqueries all seem to be totally independent of the primary query - I can't get at 'c.name' to compare it to 'c2.name'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself - there's a Criterion available through Restrictions.sqlRestriction that allows custom SQL to be used in criteria.  Here's the criteria equivalent to my HQL in the question:

```
def name = 'foo'

def crit = session.createCriteria(Card.class)
def subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Card.class, 'c2')

subcrit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction('this_.name = c2_.name'))
subcrit.setProjection(Projections.max('id'))

crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('name', "%${name}%"))
    .add(Subqueries.propertyIn('id', subcrit))

def result = crit.list()
```

There's some kind of bug with the alias-resolution in sqlRestriction() - supposedly I can use `{c2}.name` in the expression and have Hibernate generate correct SQL, but I found I had to manually write out `this_` and `c2_` for the correct SQL to generate.

Look at [How to log SQL statements in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568507/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-grails)  to see how to log the generated SQL and discover the correct names to use for your own database.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility, to use a value from your criteria in your subcriteria (in my opinion more clearer):

```
def name = 'foo'

def crit = session.createCriteria(Card.class, 'c1')
def subcrit = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Card.class, 'c2')

subcrit.add(Restrictions.eqProperty('c1.name', 'c2.name'))
subcrit.setProjection(Projections.max('c1.id'))

crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('c1.name', "%${name}%"))
    .add(Subqueries.propertyIn('c1.id', subcrit))

def result = crit.list()
```

Make sure that you place an alias e.g. `c1` for your main-criteria and use the restriction function `eqProperty()` to compare both values.

See also: [Hibernate Java Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eqProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))