# Logging SQL queries for specific files in Grails

Tags: sql, grails, logging

I am trying to make SQL queries output into the log in my grails app, and I found out how to do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568507/how-to-log-sql-statements-in-grails):

However, I want SQL logging for only specific files in my project.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not possible.  The grails loggers are turned on and off by class or package name of the code doing the logging. In this case, these are core Hibernate and / or Grails classes, so they either log all activity or no activity.

What you can do is add your own logging statements in your code before and after the operations you are interested in.  Then you can use grep to find your marker statements in the log file.  The SQL logging you are interested in will be in between your markers and you can ignore the rest of the very large log file.